# Getting ping response server information in javascript (browser + chrome aPP)

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, header, google-chrome-app

I am trying to ping some web server and want to know information of replying web server.If some proxy is in between then it should return information of that web proxy.For example ping server is- http://www.google.com  and consider following two scenario

1:-In normal scenario it should give information http://www.google.com or its ip- address
2:-In case of airport ie some proxy involved it should return airport.com or its ip instead of http://www.google.com

For this i have tried Ajax call but not able to figure out which one is returning response because in header none field of this type information present.By doing Ajax call i am able to figure out whether http://www.google.com is alive or dead.

Please suggest some alternative for browser and chrome app.

Comment: There are really two questions here: (1) whether the information is present in the headers, and (2) how to retrieve the headers. If you have any info on question (1), please post it, so we'll know which of the two questions you have (or maybe both). For (2), if Ajax isn't giving you the full info that you know is there, try the underlying API, XMLHttpRequest, which isn't much harder to use. Also, please post the code, preferably reduced to the smallest example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Use the chrome.sockets API.